# Places API parsing Lat/Lng using Java Client API

Tags: android, httpresponse, google-api-java-client, google-places-api

I want to create an android app that plots establishments on the map near the user's current location. As of now I am able to execute the request and print the response (such as id, name, vicinity, etc) except for the **lat** and **lng** values. 
I am certain that I am getting the response needed as you can see from this logcat message:

[image]

The following is how I access/print the retrieved values:
-- *As stated in the commented lines, the first line of code that accesses the 'name' inside 'for' works while second one does not.*

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(PlacesList result) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String text = "Result \n";

if (result!=null){
    for(Place place: result.results) {
        // This works   
        text = text + place.name +"\n";

        // This doesn't
        text = text + place.geometry.location.lat +"\n";
    }
    txt1.setText(text);
}
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
}
```

I'm guessing the problem is probably caused by the way the model (source: [link](http://tchdp.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-google-data-java-client-api-for.html)) is handled:
    -- *It may be important to note that declaring (and leaving it un-commented) **public  Geometry geometry;** completely prevents me from retrieving any response values (id, name, etc.).*

```
public class PlacesList {
@Key
public String status;

@Key
public List<Place> results;
}
```

```
public class Place {
    @Key
    public String id;

    @Key
    public String name;

    @Key
    public String reference;

    @Key
    public String vicinity;

    @Key
    public String icon;

    // Leaving this line prevents me from retrieving any of the above values    
    @Key
    public Geometry geometry;

    // On the other hand, declaring non-existing elements (elements that are not
    // included on the Place Search response) does not break the program 
    // at all (i.e. values from valid elements such as id, name, etc. can be retrieved) 
    @Key
    public String testFakeElement;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " - " + id + " - " + reference;
    }
}
```

```
public class Geometry {
    @Key
    public Location location;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return location.toString();
    }

    public class Location {
        @Key
        public double lat;

        @Key
        public double lng;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Double.toString(lat) + ", " + Double.toString(lng);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. 
As I've thought, the model itself is what's preventing me from retrieving lat/lang. 
Info from this blog has helped: [link](http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011_07_17_archive.html)

I took out the Geometry class and just added the following inside the Place class:

```
@Key
public Geometry geometry;

public static class Geometry {   
    @Key
    public Location location;
}

public static class Location {
    @Key
    public double lat;

    @Key
    public double lng;

    public String toString() {
        return Double.toString(lat) + ", " + Double.toString(lng);
    }
}
```